# Bash profile syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, tmux

Getting `-bash: ~/.profile: syntax error: unexpected end of file` when I start tmux but not when starting terminal. Tried running dos2unix but it couldn't fix the issue. Please help

This is my ~/.profile file.

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH";
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH";
fi
```

Comment: Your `.profile` looks good but it's possible that `"$HOME/.bashrc"` is broken. Can you post it?

Comment: Here it is: https://ideone.com/CIUqxx

Comment: I noticed in your .bashrc that there is "alias fi", if-fi are keywords, maybe it creates troubles ... try to comment it in .bashrc. Just a tip.

Comment: @HonzaP. That fixed the issue. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: OK, I put it as an answer. Please mark it. You are welcome :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in your .bashrc that there is "alias fi", if-fi are keywords, maybe it creates troubles ... try to comment it in .bashrc. Just a tip.